# How to found different in list

Tags: list, groovy, unique

I have a list with the next value (for example) -

```
[{branches='master', include='*.jar,*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.rar'},
 {branches='', include='*.txt,*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.rar'}]
```

List can have a more than 2 lines. In above example only *exclude* is correct.
I need to use unique, for found different values for branches, include and exclude.  Maybe it is possobility to use size for found different

> unique(){ }.size()

I need throw error if branches='master' and branches='foo' for example. And the same for include and exclude.
If i have below values in list in example, it is will be **correct** for me. Help please to find different in list

```
[{branches='master', include='*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.jar'},
 {branches='master', include='*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.jar'}]
```

Comment: First, check that both maps have the same keys. Then check for each key in map1 that map1[key] == map2[key]

Comment: i already tried to compare map, but list can have 5 or more lines -  
[{branches='master', include='*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.jar'},  
{branches='master', include='*.jar,*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.rar'},  
{branches='master', include='*.jar,*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.rar'},  
{branches='', include='*.txt,*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.rar'},  
 {branches='master', include='*.pom,*.zip', exclude='*.jar'}]

Comment: then `maps.unique().size()` should work! If it's not 1, then at least one map is different.

Comment: i'm testing it but with different value i always get 1

Comment: Where is the data coming from? What class do the maps have? If the `.unique()` operator doesn't work it must be because of how this class is built.

Comment: @Ivan, show your code, example input and expected output. then someone may help you.